# WPF CosmosDB ReadNextAsync() hangs when is calling in background_worker

Tags: wpf, async-await, azure-cosmosdb

In WPF I have background_worker and in it I have to make request to Cosmos DB, request that use iterator:

```cs
_worker_GenerateReport.DoWork += _worker_GenerateReport_DoWork;
```

This is method for backgroundWorker:

```cs
void _worker_GenerateReport_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
var result = QueryItemsAsync2(connectionString, queryToDownloadData.ToString());
```

And method. In this method on `GetAwaiter().GetResult();` it hangs:

```cs
private async Task<IEnumerable<DTO_Proj>> QueryItemsAsync2(
    ConnectionString connectionString, string sqlQueryText)
{
    QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
    var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(connectionString.DatabaseID, 
        connectionString.Collection);
    
    FeedIterator<DTO_Proj> resultSet = 
        container.GetItemQueryIterator<DTO_Proj>(queryDefinition,
            requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
            {
                //MaxItemCount = 1000,
                MaxConcurrency = 1
            });
    
    while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
    {
        Task<FeedResponse<DTO_Proj>> response = resultSet.ReadNextAsync();
        var result = response.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

---

I have to write once again. I removed `BackgroundWorker` and I see that the problem is with fetching items from `CosmosDB`.
Now I have in xaml button:

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Command="{Binding Path=Command_GenerateReport2}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsUIEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">report2</Button>
```

in `MVVM` command is created as follow:

```
Command_GenerateReport2 = new MVVM.RelayCommand(p => Can_GenerateReport(), a => generateReport2());
```

Method generateReport2:

```
  private void generateReport2()
  {
       ConnectionString connectionString = CreateConnectionStringAzureDB(serverToUse);

       string queryTest = " SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Proj = 2544912 ";

       var result = QueryItemsAsync2(connectionString, queryTest);
   }
```

And method QueryItemsAsync2:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<DTO_Proj>> QueryItemsAsync2(ConnectionString connectionString, string sqlQueryText)
  {
            QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);

            var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(connectionString.DatabaseID, connectionString.Collection);

            FeedIterator<DTO_Proj> resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<DTO_Proj>(
                queryDefinition,
                requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
                {
                    MaxItemCount = 1000,
                    MaxConcurrency = 1
                });

    while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    Task<FeedResponse<DTO_Proj>> response = resultSet.ReadNextAsync();
                   
                    response.Wait();
...
```

And I have two `CosmosDB` containers. On one of them `resultSet.ReadNextAsync()` works and on the second hangs on this line. Configuration of these containers I think is the same. The difference is that on one container there is a lot of data and application hangs on it, on the second works but there is little data.

Comment: Don't use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, just await the task directly.  You are in an `async` `Task` returning method, so there should be no issues.

Comment: I'm also not entirely clear why you are running an `async` method on a `BackgroundWorker`. You shouldn't need to do that at all.

Comment: I've removed async from my code, but application still hangs

Comment: Where does your application hang? Is it hanging inside `QueryItemsAsync2` method?

Comment: You would probably have better luck going entirely `async`, rather than trying to use the `BackgroundWorker`. Is there some technical requirement to use it?

Comment: It hangs on waiting from result
Now I'm trying to remove `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: @Robert: Your `QueryItemsAsync2` won't even compile. What does it return?

Comment: @mm8 I addes second version of code, because I've writtend next version without BackgroundWorker.

Comment: `QueryItemsAsync2` still doesn't compile. And you still don't need  background worker. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the items *asynchronously* and not block by calling `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`:

```
while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
{
    var item = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();
    ...
}
```

Then you don't need to use a `BackgroundWorker` or involve any background threads. You could simply call and await the asynchronous `QueryItemsAsync2` method:

```
var result = await QueryItemsAsync2(connectionString, queryToDownloadData.ToString());
```

Comment: I did like you wrote, but result the same, on one container it works on the second hangs on `var item = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();` line

Comment: What "container"?

Comment: container in CosmosDB